# Scroll to bottom to div when data loads dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a chat application, wheneve I send my message it works fine and it keep the scroll to bottom **BUT** on the other side I receive the message but it doesn't scroll to latest message received!

I am using following query to scroll to bottom when I send message

```
<script>
var $cont = $('.con1');
$cont[0].scrollTop = $cont[0].scrollHeight;

$('.inp').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $cont.append('<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>');
        $cont[0].scrollTop = $cont[0].scrollHeight;
        $(this).val('');
    }
})
.focus();

</script>
```

And this is AJAX code for retrieving messages from mySQL database

```
    function get_messages() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/get_messages.php',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          $('.msg-wgt-body').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

**How to automatically scroll to latest message**

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

```
      <div class="msg-wgt-body con1" id="Box">
    <table>
      <?php
      if (!empty($messages)) {
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
          $msg = htmlentities($message['message'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
          $user_name = ucfirst($message['username']);
          $sent = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
          echo <<<MSG
          <tr class="msg-row-container">
            <td>
              <div class="msg-row">
                <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="user-label"><a href="#" style="color: #6D84B4;">{$user_name}</a> <span class="msg-time">{$sent}</span></span><br/>{$msg}
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
         MSG;
        }
      } else {
        echo '<span style="margin-left: 25px;">No chat messages available!</span>';
      }
      ?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should call scroll after you insert html in ajax. How your html looks like?

Comment: So, what have you tried when you receive the message?

Answer (score 2):

The following would simplify your predicament:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<p>Message 1</p>
<p>Message 2</p>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Then you can scroll to the top or bottom easily:

```
$("#bottom").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

So in your Ajax call:

```
function get_messages() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/get_messages.php',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $('.msg-wgt-body').html(data);
      $("#bottom").get(0).scrollIntoView();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @RobertoLinares are you looking at the options?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I got confused with `scrollIntoViewOptions`. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make your scroll code reusable and call it when enter is pressed and when you update via ajax. Along the same lines, decoupling your submit code form the input's enter key means you can add a submit button without duplicating the callback.

```
var chatApp = {};
chatApp.cont = $('.con1')[0];
chatApp.input = $('.inp')[0]

chatApp.scrollToEnd = function() {
    chatApp.cont.scrollTop = chatApp.cont.scrollHeight;
};

chatApp.input.on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        chatApp.chatSubmit();
    }
})
.focus();

// make submit reusable so that you can attach a submit button
$('.chat-submit').on('click', chatApp.chatSubmit);

chatApp.chatSubmit = function() {
    chatApp.cont.append('<p>' + chatApp.input.val() + '</p>');
    chatApp.scrollToEnd();
    chatApp.input.val('');
}


chatApp.get_messages() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/get_messages.php',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.msg-wgt-body').html(data);
            chatApp.scrollToEnd();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

element.scrollBy(0, 100000000)

It works....

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.